# How to use QWebView as Stand alone JavaScript engine?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit, qwebview

In my current project, we were using c++, QT, QTWebview. Complete business logic resides in JavaScript which was loaded into the .exe/.app using QWebView. Native OS logic resides in C++. The to and fro communication from C++ to Javascript is heavy achieved using QT Signal & Slots . Inside Javascript, we were also using HTML5 web workers, just to make sure the C++ QT UI thread is responsive to the end user.

In fact, the Javascript doesn't need any DOM interactions. We were using Javascript as a plain programming language. As the complete QT webkit involves both Layout engine & Javascript engine. I feel that memory consumption is some what heavy.

Will it be possible to use QWebView as plain Javascript engine?

Also It will be great if you can suggest me any best memory management techniques dealing with QWebView. We are seeing the memory consumption is growing heavily

Comment: Have you considered using [Qt Script](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/scripting.html)?

Comment: Hi Roku.. Thanks for your reply. Just had a quick walk through of it to see if it suits my needs. Looks like it doesn't support XMLHttpRequest. My current project require this to fetch data from external resources.